# What is the largest, noncrystalline, non-polymer inorganic molecule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecules

A question came up in class from one of my chemistry students. He asked what the largest, non-crystal, non carbon-based, molecule is. We ruled out complex proteins, DNA, and other polymers, as well as crystalline structures and metals from the list. I didn't have an answer for him, so I looked it up but could not find a definite answer. I found two threads on Reddit, listed below. Polyoxometalates come up, but without any specifics. I know "largest" can be subjective, so please specify if the molecule is "largest" because of its physical size or because of its mass.

https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/2phl4s/whats_the_largest_inorganic_molecule_you_know/

https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/i6v07/what_is_the_biggest_noncrystalline_inorganic/

Comment: I noticed someone down-voted my question. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: You didn't exclude amorphous substances... Another thing is what you call a polymer? Polyoxometalates already have quite repetitive structure. If you link together some big fullerenes, at which point it would become "a polymer"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the redditors that the answer is likely a polyoxometalate.

$\ce{Na48[H_xMo368O1032(H2O)240(SO4)48] · \text{ca.}~1000 H2O}$ aka
$\ce{\{Mo368\}}$ (core: $M \approx\pu{60.7 kDa},$ dimensions $\approx \pu{2.5 nm} × \pu{4.0 nm})$ is the primary candidate [[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/1521-3773(20020402)41:7%3C1162::AID-ANIE1162%3E3.0.CO;2-8)]:

> [image]
>
> **Figure 2**. Structure of **1a** in crystals of **1** in polyhedral (**a**) and ball and stick (**b**) representation perpendicular to the $C_4$ axis and along the $C_4$ axis ((**c**) and (**d**); building units $\ce{\{Mo1\}}$ yellow, $\ce{\{Mo2\}}$ red, $\ce{\{Mo(Mo5)\}}$ blue with blue-turquoise pentagonal bipyramids; $\ce{O}$ atoms small red spheres, $\ce{S}$ atoms gray spheres).
> Note that one capping part is turned against the other by $360/16^\circ.$
> The different building blocks and the arrays of different local symmetry are assigned.

A recent review of mass-spectrometry studies of large polyoxometalates is also available [[2](https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.6b00070)].

#### References

1. Müller, A.; Beckmann, E.; Bögge, H.; Schmidtmann, M.; Dress, A. Inorganic Chemistry Goes Protein Size: A $\ce{Mo368}$ Nano-Hedgehog Initiating Nanochemistry by Symmetry Breaking. *Angewandte Chemie International Edition* **2002**, 41 (7), 1162–1167. DOI: [10.1002/1521-3773(20020402)41:7<1162::AID-ANIE1162>3.0.CO;2-8](https://doi.org/10.1002/1521-3773(20020402)41:7%3C1162::AID-ANIE1162%3E3.0.CO;2-8).
2. Surman, A. J.; Robbins, P. J.; Ujma, J.; Zheng, Q.; Barran, Perdita. E.; Cronin, L. Sizing and Discovery of Nanosized Polyoxometalate Clusters by Mass Spectrometry. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2016**, 138 (11), 3824–3830. DOI: [10.1021/jacs.6b00070](https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.6b00070).

Comment: Are these things really molecules?

Comment: @Alchimista. Yes, they are. I'm not sure about this one, but majority of polyoxometalates is also stable in appropriate solution, and some even in gas phase.

Comment: Isn't the prefix "poly" a give away vs the question?

Comment: @Beerhunter "*Poly-*" in polyoxometalates (POMs) usually refers to the presence of more than three metal centers linked via oxo-bridges. Under given conditions, one usually doesn't get all sorts of molecules/chains/blobs etc. of POMs, only one type of species. There is no molecular mass distribution to speak of, as one would, for example, in case of traditional organic polymers.

Comment: @andselisk so the nomenclature states that if its three or more,  tri, tetra etc aren't used and the reference is simply "poly"?

Comment: @Beerhunter Why? POM is a collective term, and "poly" preserves original meaning (many). For example, you can name cyclic anion $\ce{[V4O12]^4-}$ equally as tetravanadate(V) or polyoxovanadate in general. If you are interested in inorganic nomenclature of POMs, take a look at the IUPAC Red Book, namely *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry II: Recommendations 2000* (ISBN 978-0-85404-487-0). This and many other cases are covered in there. Don't try to superimpose organic polymers with POMs, it doesn't work like that. If you are looking for the organic analogy, then it's proteins.